# Is it possible to save a file from cloud storage to my computer files?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am currently running a process that uploads a database to bigquery, I query and manipulate the data then send this data back to my google cloud storage. However I want to automate this file being sent to slack however I need it to be saved to my files to do this. I can export a file from my GCS to BQ but cant figure out how to export a file to my computer. Thanks for the help. I am using python.

```
def export_data_to_gcs(data, test12, destination):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(data)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table('test12')
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.extract_table_to_storage(
        job_name, table, 'gs://firebase_results/test12.csv')
    job.source_format = 'CSV'

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)



def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)

export_data_to_gcs(data, 'test12', destination)
```

This is the code I have so far that exports the table from BQ to my cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Heres to all that would need it. Similar to the answer given above with slight modifications.

```
client = storage.Client(project=data)
bucket = client.get_bucket('firebase_results')
blob = bucket.blob('test2.csv')
with open('test2.csv', 'w') as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've exported the table to GCS you can use the GCS client to download the file:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_file

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

client = storage.Client(project='my-project')
bucket = client.get_bucket('firebase_results')
encryption_key = 'c7f32af42e45e85b9848a6a14dd2a8f6'
blob = Blob('test12.csv', bucket, encryption_key=encryption_key)
with open('/tmp/my-downloaded-file', 'wb') as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

Comment: Ive been trying this in multiple different ways but keep getting this error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'path''  if i try download_to_file or this error if i try download_to_filename 'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found'